# Mapping a model fields with a non model fields in a ModelForm

Tags: django

I've spent nearly the whole day reading the documentation about `forms` and `ModelForms`. I managed to use the basic stuff but now I'm having really trouble because I don't find any hints in the documentation about mapping model field with non-model fields. That's what I mean:

I have this model:

```
class Process(models.Model):
    key         = models.CharField(max_length=32, default="")
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    path        = models.CharField(max_length=215)
    author      = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    canparse    = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
    last_exec   = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
    last_stop   = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
    last_change = models.DateTimeField(null = True, auto_now=True)
```

The only fields that the users are going to modify are `name` and `author`. `path` is the absolute real path of the configuration file of my Process. The directory is fixed, users are not going to care whether the directory is `/home/measure/conf` or `/var/whatever`), they only care about the filename. That's why I want a `filename` field in my `ModelForm`.

My form looks like:

```
class ProcessForm(MonitorForm):
    filename = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    class Meta:
        model  = Process
        fields = ('name', 'filename', 'author')
```

Now, what I want is that `filename` contains the file name stored in `Process.path` and not the entire path, that's what I mean:

```
>>> from monitor.forms import ProcessForm
>>> from remusdb.models import Process
>>> 
>>> p = Process(name="test1", path="/tmp/config/a.cnf", author="pablo")
>>> f = ProcessForm(instance=p)
>>> print f["filename"].value()
---> here I want to get "a.cnf"
```

The problem is I don't know how to write `a.cnf` to the `filename` field once I call `ProcessForm(instance=p)`. I thought about doing it in the `clean` function but I'm not sure whether this is a good place at all. I assume that at this point it would be too late, because the fields are more or less read-only, once initilaized you cannot change their value. So how should I do it? Should I create a custom field and override `__init__`?

I got this idea from reading [form field default cleaning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning) and wanted to test if first. I didn't want to override **init** first and I thought of first playing with  the`to_python` method like in the documentation. So I created the class `RemusFilenameField`:

```
class RemusFilenameField(forms.CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        print "to_python's value is %s" % value
        return value.upper()

    def clean(self, value):
        print "clean's value is %s" % value
        return value.upper()
```

and changed the `filename` line on `ProcessForm` to

```
filename = RemusFilenameField(max_length=250)
```

I added the prints to see where/when this methods get called. But the methods are not called at all. I suspect because the form is not bounded. So I did this instead:

```
>>> p = {"name": "test1", "filename": "a.cnf", "author": "pablo"}
>>> f = ProcessForm(p)
>>> f.is_valid()
clean's value is a.cnf
True
>>> print f["filename"].value()
a.cnf
```

The `to_python` method is also not getting called and I expected to see `A.CNF` because `clean` returns the something different.

I have no idea how to solve this and even whether this was a good idea at all. My next probelm is when `f.save()` is executed the correct `path` has to be generated out of `filename` and stored in the `instance`. I would do that in the `clean` method or is there a better options for this?

**EDIT**: I think I have a solution for the creation of the form (I had to read the whole source code to identify in `python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py` the `model_to_dict` usage:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
import os

class ProcessForm(MonitorForm):
   filename = RemusFilenameField(max_length=250)
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(ProcessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       try:
           proc = kwargs["instance"]
           filename = os.path.basename(proc.path)
           self.initial.update({'filename': unicode(filename)})
       except:
           pass
   class Meta:
       model  = Process
       fields = ('name', 'filename', 'author')
```

It know works :) now I have to figure out how to fix the `save()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The save() method is the appropriate place to put any additional save logic in your form.

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    proc = super(ProcessForm, self).save(commit=False)
    filename = cleaned_data['filename']
    # additional logic to alter filename
    proc.path = filename
    if commit:
        proc.save()
    return proc
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense and it's more easier than the "load" part. After reading the source code of `django.forms.models` it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of calling `to_python()` method on the field in your form your code is correct, but you have to get value from [cleaned_data dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form):

```
>>> p = {"name": "test1", "filename": "a.cnf", "author": "pablo"}
>>> f = ProcessForm(p)
>>> f.is_valid()
clean's value is a.cnf
True
>>> f.cleaned_data['filename']
'A.CNF'
```

If you need some logic on model save you can override `save()` in model. It's also described in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).

You should also consider to override `save()` [method in your ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) as drewman said - it won't affect your code on calling `save()` method on model instance from other places in your code.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I didn't think about the `cleaned_data` at all. The problem was that may view still wasn't displaying `A.CNF` but `a.cnf`. But I found a solution that works from the beginning, although I am not very happy with it. If the internal parts of `ModelForm` changes then my code will have to be changed again.